# iPhone Programming: Data not coming into App on iPhone 4 running 5.1.1 on AT&T only

Tags: iphone, ios, cellular-network

Need Help Immediately!

We have an app that has been approved, but we are getting reports that users with an iPhone 4, running 5.1.1 on AT&T are not getting data showing in their application.

Another strange thing is that if I connect using Verizon Mi-Fi, it works, but if I connect using an AT&T mi-fi, it doesn't work.

We have tested the following and have verified that it works on the following:

> iPhone 4S, 5.1.1 on AT&T, Wi-Fi
>   iPad 2, 5.1.1 on AT&T 3G, Wi-Fi
>   iPhone 4, 5.1.1 on Verizon, Wi-Fi
>   iPhone 4, 5.1.1 on Sprint, Wi-Fi
>   iPhone 4S, 5.1.1 on Verizon, Wi-Fi

The devices aren't jailbroken or unlocked and came straight from AT&T. Also, the information that is coming from our server is a JSON payload.

If you need any more information or you heard of this problem before, please let me know. We really need help on this.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Have you attached the debugger in that situation. You need to check 1. If there is any response, 2. If there are any errors.

Comment: I recall a while ago there was a question with a similar problem, though I can't find it readily now. The problem turned out to be they were asking for a specific port during a networking operation instead of letting the OS pick one for them. Just a thought.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with AT&T assembly syntax - retagged as `[cellular-network]`.

Answer (score 0):

Things I would look at:

- are you requesting a specific port
- are you accessing a blacklisted URL / IP (can you get at it in a browser)
- are you sending or receiving shaped / blocked packets (e.g. P2P data)

Answer (score 0):

One thing you might check - sometimes servers are overly sensitive about HTTP headers (e.g. the user agent string), and it's possible that some ISPs might modify certain HTTP headers, and the server isn't serving up what it should.

I've seen badly configured servers that were setup to serve different files to mobile and desktop users - when it came to serving up JSON through an API, the server attempted to "redirect" to some other resource due to the HTTP user-agent string including the string "Mobile".

Assuming you have access to a configuration that *isn't* working, you could use a HTTP tracing utility like [HTTPScoop](http://tuffcode.com) (which will show you the request/response headers) to try and diagnose what's going wrong. Comparing the working/non-working request and response headers may track down your problem. If your ISP is modifying HTTP headers, you probably won't be able to see that in HTTPScoop, but the response code/headers may still be helpful.